# How to get data from Observable that receives data from third-party API

Tags: angular, rxjs

Newby in Reactive programming (and Angular).

I just want to make my first data stream and get something else than error in console output :)

This is my try:

```
export class AppComponent { 

  requestStream: any;

    constructor(){  
       this.requestStream = Observable.of('https://api.github.com/users').do(console.log).subscribe();  
    }
```

Error:

> AppComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR TypeError:
>   **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_rxjs_observable**.Observable.of is not a function

So what I want is to get any kind of object in my console. Please help me to make my first step into Reactive programming.

p.s. should I use a `get` Http protocol to get that url? Tried something like:

```
constructor(http: Http) {
this.url = http.get('https://api.github.com/users');
this.requestStream = Observable.of(this.url).do(console.log).subscribe(); 
}
```

But faced the same error...

Comment: Why don't you just `http.get('https://api.github.com/users').subscribe((res)=>console.log(res));`?

Comment: All Http `get` methods brings observables?

Comment: That brings an observable. My best advice to you would be to read angulars official documentation. Don't read deprecated/wrong tutorials from people you don't know.

Comment: Hm... Yes, I see now that it brings Observable... If you dont post an answer I will delete this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply make an http call which returns an observable:

```typescript
http.get('https://api.github.com/users').subscribe((res)=>co‌​nsole.log(res));
```

Source to `http.get`: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/http/src/http.ts#L130